# OleDb Exception was unhandled

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I seem to be getting a OleDb Exception was unhandled when running this code and i really cant see why...

Code attached
Thanks!
James

```
Module DataAccess
    Private Builder As New OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With
        {
            .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0",
            .DataSource = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Database1.accdb")
        }
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Used to remove the current item selected in the txtFirstName text box.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Name"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub RemmoveFemale(ByVal Name As String)
        Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With
                {
                    .ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString
                }
            Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn}
                cmd.CommandText =
                    <SQL>
                        DELETE FROMCustomerNames WHERE CustomerName = @CustomerName
                    </SQL>.Value

                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter With {.DbType = DbType.String, .ParameterName = "@CustomerName", .Value = Name})

                cn.Open()
                Dim Affected As Int32 = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Called in Form1 on FormClosing event to update the database table if
    ''' needed.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub UpdateFemaleNames(ByVal sender As AutoCompleteStringCollection)
        Dim NewNames As New List(Of String)

        Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With
                {
                    .ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString
                }
            Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn}
                cmd.CommandText =
                    <SQL>
                        SELECT CustomerName
                        FROM CustomerNames
                        WHERE CustomerName = @CustomerName
                    </SQL>.Value

                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter With {.DbType = DbType.String, .ParameterName = "@CustomerName"})

                cn.Open()

                For x As Int32 = 0 To sender.Count - 1
                    cmd.Parameters("@CustomerName").Value = sender.Item(x)
                    Dim Result As String = CStr(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
                    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Result) Then
                        NewNames.Add(sender.Item(x))
                    End If
                Next

                If NewNames.Count > 0 Then
                    cmd.CommandText =
                        <SQL>
                                INSERT INTO CustomerNames (CustomerName,Gender) VALUES (@CustomerNamee,@Gender)
                            </SQL>.Value

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter With {.DbType = DbType.String, .ParameterName = "@Gender", .Value = "Female"})

                    For Each Item In NewNames
                        cmd.Parameters("@CustomerName").Value = Item
                        cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    Next

                End If

            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Used in Form1 DataGridView1 for learning purposes only
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Function AllFemaleNames() As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With
                {
                    .ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString
                }
            Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn}
                cmd.CommandText =
                    <SQL>
                        SELECT Identifier, CustomerName
                        FROM CustomerNames
                        WHERE Gender = 'Female'
                        ORDER BY CustomerName;
                    </SQL>.Value

                cn.Open()

                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

            End Using
        End Using

        Return dt
    End Function
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Load only female first names into the auto complete source
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Function LoadFemaleNames() As AutoCompleteStringCollection
        Dim TheNameList As New AutoCompleteStringCollection


        Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With
                {
                    .ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString
                }
            Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn}
                cmd.CommandText =
                    <SQL>
                        SELECT CustomerName
                        FROM CustomerNames
                        WHERE Gender = 'Female'
                        ORDER BY CustomerName;
                    </SQL>.Value

                cn.Open()
                Dim Reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

                If Reader.HasRows Then
                    While Reader.Read
                        TheNameList.Add(Reader.GetString(0))
                    End While

                    Reader.Close()

                End If

            End Using
        End Using

        Return TheNameList

    End Function

End Module








Module StringExtensions
    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function ProperCase(ByVal sender As String) As String
        Dim TI As System.Globalization.TextInfo = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", False).TextInfo
        Return TI.ToTitleCase(sender.ToLower)
    End Function
End Module







''' <summary>
''' Simple demo for auto complete adding items that are not in the list when pressing ENTER in TextBox1.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        UpdateFemaleNames(txtFirstName.AutoCompleteCustomSource)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        txtFirstName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
        txtFirstName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        txtFirstName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = LoadFemaleNames()
        ' The next two lines are for demo purposes only to see what is in the list for the TextBox with First names
        DataGridView1.DataSource = AllFemaleNames()
        DataGridView1.Columns("CustomerName").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtFirstName.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstName.Text) Then
                If Not txtFirstName.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Contains(txtFirstName.Text.ToLower) Then
                    txtFirstName.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(txtFirstName.Text.ProperCase)
                End If

                txtFirstName.Text = txtFirstName.Text.ProperCase

                e.SuppressKeyPress = True

            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub cmdRemoveName_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdRemoveName.Click
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstName.Text) Then
            Dim CurrentName As String = txtFirstName.Text.Trim.ProperCase
            If My.Dialogs.Question(String.Format("Remove '{0}'", CurrentName)) Then
                RemmoveFemale(CurrentName)
                txtFirstName.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Remove(txtFirstName.Text)
                txtFirstName.Text = ""
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking. Where is the error occurring? What does the exception message say? You have posted a wall of code without any real explanation of what is going on, or what you have tried to resolve it.

Comment: Hi its when i try to debug the code i get the error, it runs with 1 error saying this : an OleDb exception was unhandled. An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters. i have scanned the code and checked the MDB's table and feild names against teh CustomerName field on the code

Comment: Visual Studio usually automatically stop at the line that caused the error.  Do you know which line might be causing the problem.  There are over a dozen instances in your code that could be causing this issue. See the article at - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn - for a basic guide on how to debug in visual studio.  Identify the line and the error message if you can.

Comment: Hi Kami. all the error dialog gives me is {"No value given for one or more required parameters."}, and i really cant see where it is in the code, when ever i have come accross this before it would usially identify where in the code the error is, so i could resolve it. would it help if i were to upload the files to a skydrive?

Comment: the files are on : https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=64360DBD4BB0A8FC!117&authkey=!AADy9WwqsZjWH64 - Named Project1

Comment: I suggest you remove the files from there. There is no need for me to download/debug code.

Comment: Hi Kami, that didnt make any difference to the code, i have uploaded a screenshot of where Visual studio identifies the error, : https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=64360DBD4BB0A8FC!118&authkey=!AFbaCt086KzcY5c&v=3 ,

Answer (score 0):

Without exact location of the error it is difficult to identify where the problem is originating from.

However, given the error message it seems like one or more of your statements contain parameters that are not provided. The following code

```
If NewNames.Count > 0 Then
    cmd.CommandText =
        <SQL>
             INSERT INTO CustomerNames (CustomerName,Gender) VALUES (@CustomerNamee,@Gender)
        </SQL>.Value

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter With {.DbType = DbType.String, .ParameterName = "@Gender", .Value = "Female"})

    For Each Item In NewNames
        cmd.Parameters("@CustomerName").Value = Item
        cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Next

End If
```

the name of the customer parameters is spelt `@CustomerNamee`.  Adjust these or change the if statement to something like

```
If NewNames.Count > 0 Then
    cmd.CommandText =
        <SQL>
             INSERT INTO CustomerNames (CustomerName,Gender) VALUES (@CustomerName,@Gender)
        </SQL>.Value

    For Each Item In NewNames
        cmd.Parameters("@CustomerName").Value = Item
        cmd.Parameters("@Gender").Value = "Female";
        cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Next
End If
```

Comment: i Kami, that didnt make any difference to the code, i have uploaded a screenshot of where Visual studio identifies the error, : https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=64360DBD4BB0A8FC!118&authkey=!AFbaCt086KzcY5c&v=3

Comment: @user2893909 That screen shot seems to suggest an error at a different section of the code. Can you confirm if the connection string is valid; and that the table exists. Also, if you click the "View Detail" in the exception box, it will give you more information on what the error actually is.

Comment: Yes the table exists i have checked the name against the code, Screensnap of View detials: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=64360DBD4BB0A8FC!119&authkey=!AJNteqTsaQG97AY&v=3 , the forum suggests opening a live chat, instaed of conversing via the forum would this work with you? thanks James

Comment: @user2893909 Have you tried running the query directly against the database?

Comment: I'm not sure how i would go about this? I'm using Microsoft Access as a B/E

Comment: Try - http://www.wikihow.com/Run-a-Query-in-MS-Access-2007 - At step 9 type in the query above, and run.  This should give you more detailed error message.

Comment: Hi I get an error saying You cannot use ODBC to import from , export to, or link to an external microsoft access or ISAM database table to your database

Comment: I have tried all of the options here in the property sheet, ived tried linking the access file, ive tried SQL, ive tried the default Access on but dosent seem to wokr

Comment: @user2893909 Look into why you are not able to run queries on your database directly.  Once you have that resolved, check your connection string. The issue seems to be with the connection to database.

Comment: @user2893909 Can you post your table structure, along with the field names and data types? Perhaps we are missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Right from the start, I see this line in your code, which would cause that error:

```
DELETE FROMCustomerNames WHERE CustomerName = @CustomerName
```

And it should be this:

```
DELETE FROM CustomerNames WHERE CustomerName = @CustomerName
```

There was no space between FROM and CustomerNames

Comment: See comments on my answer. The problem seems to be on form load.

Comment: @kami Figured it out after getting thier database and trying to run the query myself. See my OTHER answer.

Comment: I have resolved the issue, it was a line in the code, miss matching the description on the table, thanks for your help, Steve and Kami

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL:

```
SELECT CustomerName
FROM CustomerNames
WHERE Gender = 'Female'
ORDER BY CustomerName;
```

You refer to a column that does not exist. Access thinks you are asking for a parameter, which you are not, so you get the error you mentioned. Try this instead:

```
SELECT CustomerNames
FROM CustomerNames
WHERE Gender = 'Female'
ORDER BY CustomerNames;
```

It is a bad idea to name fields and tables, or any other objects for that matter, with the same name. This comes with experience but you must trust me on this.

Comment: Hey @Steve thanks for your reply, i appreciate the support and of course trust the guidance given. I have ammended both sections of the code but still get the error. any other ideas? i have the project uploaded on a skydrive if it helps for reference ? Thanks again James

Comment: I know it's on sky drive. That how I found the issue and fixed it using the code I posted. Double check your field names (both in the select and the **ORDER BY**.